# whats wrong with this?this code not insert the element at the begining of linked list

Tags: c

> linked list that add element at the begining
>   i want to add at begining but it only accept first element and then
>   treminate
>   it does not accept the other elements whats wrong with while loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_type {
    int data; struct node_type *next;
} node;
typedef node* list;

void main() {
    list head,temp; int n; char ch;

    head = NULL;
    printf("\n Enter the data:(y/n):");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y') {
        printf("\n Enter Element:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        temp = (list) malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = head;

        head = temp;
        printf("\n Enter more data:");
        scanf("%c", &ch);

    }

    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that doing `fflush(stdin)` is *undefined behavior*. Some "standard" libraries add it as an extension, but avoid it if possible.

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: Cannot parse the question, due to missing punctuation ... *sigh*. I feel this is ...

Comment: @CherubimAnand That is problematic, since if there's n other non-white-space characters after the white-space (or EOF) then `scanf` will block.

Comment: i added \n bt it again take one more number and terminated

Comment: You are not supposed to *fix* the question from the indications in the comments and answers... It makes the discussion inconsistent.  As posted in my answer, remove the `fflush(stdin);` **and** replace the formats in the `scanf("%c", &ch);` with `scanf(" %c", &ch);`  Notice the space before the `%`.

Comment: @Akshay: can you accept one of the answers by clicking n the grey checkmark below its score?

Answer (score 2):

For starters according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The format string of the call of the function `scanf` for the variable `ch` must look like

```
scanf( " %c", &ch );
       ^^^^^^
```

In this case white space characters including the new line character will be skipped. Otherwise the function will return control characters. Also you should check whether there is the end of the stream.

The while loop can look like

```
printf( "\nEnter the data:(y/n): " );

while ( scanf( " %c", &ch ) == 1 && ( ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y' ) ) 
{
    printf( "\nEnter Element: " );
    scanf( "%d", &n );

    temp = (list) malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = head;

        head = temp;
    }

    printf( "\nEnter more data: " );
}
```

Comment: Testing the return value of `scanf( "%d", &n );` is advisable. Casting the return value of `malloc()` is not.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the way you read `y/n` responses:

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

Adding the space in the format string instructs `scanf` to skip any white space characters, including the pending linefeed you are trying to get rid of with the `fflush(stdin);`, which invokes undefined behavior.

Also check the return value of `scanf()`: it should be `1`, otherwise, the conversion was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit modified code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_type {
    int data; 
    struct node_type *next;
}list;

int main() {
    list *head, *temp; int n; char ch;

    head = NULL;
    printf("\n Enter the data:(y/n):");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y') {
        printf("\n Enter Element:");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        // Inserting a node into linked list at beginning:
        // 1. Create a node and initialize its values
        //    Make sure that the next field points to current head node
        temp = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = head;

        // 2. Update the head pointer so that it points to newly created node
        head = temp;

        printf("\n Enter more data:");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);

    }

    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I also did the same thing as @Vlad and @chqrlie mentioned.

Comment: The code is not indented.  The test on `head == NULL` is useless, the `else` branch can handle all cases correctly.

Answer (score -1):

NULL is not defined in `stdio.h`you should define it manually by using `#define` macro OR by using`stddef.h` or`stdlib.h`.It will be better to use `fflush(stdin)` as it clears the input buffer(This removes unexpexted errors,while dealing with `scanf()`on characters and integers simultaneously).It is predefined in `stdio.h`

Comment: `NULL` **is** defined in `<stdio.h>` as well as other standard headers such as `<locale.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<time.h>` and `<wchar.h>`.  `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior.  Flushing pending characters from `stdin` can be done with: `scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c");`